# How to run a php file that uses wordpress functions from command line?

Tags: php, command-line

I am using wordpress functions in a custom php file including `wp-load.php`, run from browser it is fine, but run from command line with `php /path/.php` `wp-load.php` causes problems:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in /../wp-includes/ms-settings.php on line 162
```

code example to reproduce:

```
echo 'something';
require "/../wp-load.php";
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/193086/edit) to include the code you're trying to debug.

Comment: Why are you trying to include `wp-load.php` directly?

Comment: If you `echo`, you send headers, so you can not send them again or modified them. This is a pure PHP related problem not specifically related with WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress has a command line library called [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/). You can extend it to create your own commands. I would recommend this for any work on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using another php file to use from the command line with just a line like this:

`file_get_contents('url to file I want to run');`

the problem with using wordpress function in files outside of wordpress is that wordpress is bound to its installation so you gotta run it from an url belonging to the wordpress setup I think